# Error in Managed Metadata

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata

I use SharePoint 2013
My Managed Metadata simply stopped, I look in LOG and I found this errors:

1 - Failed to get term store for proxy;

2 - The Managed Metadata Service 'Service Name' is inaccessible;

I'm not stalled the KB of October, but this service are worked until recently.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Service for managed metadata in Central Admin -> Manage services on server? If started, try to stop and then start again. If you do not see Manage services on server, make sure to start Internet Explorer as administrator before navigating to Central admin.

Comment: I'm go try this

Comment: This not work man :(

Comment: And you have not changed any permissions or accounts in SharePoint or IIS? And tried basic IISRESET and restart of sptimerv4?

Comment: I try IIS reset. I not change permissions of any account

Comment: Is your service still available in CA but your sites cannot connect to your managed meta data?

Comment: I agree with @RobertLindgren that it sounds like a permissions issue. Accounts or Environment have not changed?

Comment: I agree with @RobertLindgren too. But permissions not change. I'm searching the problem.