# Problems with Managed Metadata can cause permission errors for users with permission only from a list on the site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, access-denied

**I am using Sharepoint 2013.**

I'm having problems with Managed Metadata as this question: [Managed Metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84800/error-in-managed-metadata)
I'm having error with permissions as this question: [Permissions Error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86680/problems-with-unique-permissions-in-a-list)

**My problem:**

I have a site with multiple lists. A user is allowed to view content in one of these lists, the rest of the site he has no permission.
In respect of the list of permissions the user name and your permission level appears.
When I look at the list of site permissions the user name is not there (normal). But when I do the research to find out what that user has permission on the site, no returns (should return restricted permission).
When the user tries to access the url of the list it has access denied (he had access until recently).

It is possible that my mistake managed metadata cause the loss of user access this list?

*(Check the other two question in order to better understand the context.)*